# Force Perl's Configure to disable crypto support even if it's available on the host system

Tags: perl, build, configure, libcrypto

From https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/65f7068/Configure#L12110 I'm gathering that it's `d_crypt` and `d_crypt_r` that further control if Perl detected libcrypt on the host system.

However, I didn't find how to force it to set them to undef via Configure command-line flags or via environment variables.

Should I just append `#undef d_crypt`/`#undef d_drypt_r` to the `Config.h` it generates? Is there a more proper way to instruct Perl to configure/build without libcrypt support?

Comment: Maybe you could pass option `-A clear:d_crypt` to configure? See [line 1869](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/65f7068/Configure#L1869)

Comment: Why do you want to disable crypto support?

Comment: Note that there is a builtin Perl function called [crypt](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt). Maybe it depends on a C library `crypt()` function to be available? Then you should probably not disable that support.

Comment: I'm suspecting that the scripts/modules I'm using may not need this function. As you already know in other questions, I'm making an embedded perl, so I'd rather exclude a dependency if it's not used (later I plan to build the whole thing on Alpine and use static linking) :) I'll msg again when I check if `-Aclear:d_crypt` and `-Aclear:d_crypt_r` work or not, then you could make it into an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: For now, `Aclear:d_crypt` / `-Aclear:d_crypt_r` does not seem to help. Investigating deeper...

Comment: It worked after also specifying modified ` -Dlibs="-lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lutil -lc"`. Checking if clear was needed.

Comment: So it seems that it's `-Dlibs="-lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lutil -lc"` that is defining, `-Aclear...` make no difference :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I need to add a switch `-Dlibs="-lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lutil -lc"` to the `./Configure` invocation. Originally, `libs` is set to `-lpthread -lcrypto -lnsl -ldl -lm -lutil -lc`, so I had to remove `crypto` from here.

Setting `-Aclear:d_crypt` / `-Aclear:d_crypt_r` made no difference :(

Comment: You probably mean -lcrypt, not -lcrypto, which is a different library and not normally used directly by perl